# Convert relative path to another relative path

Tags: c#, path

I have a file `test.html` on a relative path in c#:

```
string path1 = "/sites/site/folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/test.html";
```

Inside the file `test.html` I have a link to resource:

```
string path2 = "../../../subfolder4/image.jpg";
```

I want to calculate complete relative path to this resource against the same relative root as represented in `path1` to get the following `path3`:

```
string path3 = CalculateRelativePath(path1, path2);
Assert.AreEqual(path3, "/sites/site/folder/subfolder4/image.jpg");
```

Are there any standard functions to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var page = new Uri(new Uri("http://dont-care"), path1);
var path3 = new Uri(page, path2).LocalPath;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion worked exactly as expected, so I m marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard function to do this.  You could write your own function, splitting both string paths to an array (using "/"), then using the array parts which equal ".." from one, to navigate up the other array.